# I'm trying to release my MAUI iPhone app and the CollectionView and CarouselView don't bind when running under testpilot

Tags: maui, collectionview, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I’ve just released my app to a few testers on TestFlight and have come up against a massive problem.

My app contains 3 CollectionViews and 2 CarouselViews - none of which bind when released on TestFlight.

They display the correct amount of items, but there are no images and text.

They use standard code that I modeled from the Microsoft website, and they all work perfectly on every iPhone emulator and on my physical iPhone.

Any ideas

Thanks in advance

The app has been fully tested on multiple emulators and on my physical iphone and it all works as expected.

I've also tested the databinding by adding an image and label to the form and that worked perfectly, it's just the CollectionView and CarouselView that don't bind.

Comment: Have you tried a local build in release mode?  Have you checked the. Logs?  Have you added ant error handling or logging?

Comment: Hi Jason and thanks  
There are no problems showing in logs and nothing to catch in error handling. It doesn't crash, it's just not binding to the data. 
I'm currently trying to do a local build in release mode. I can get it to build ok, but it reports that it cannot upload the app to the device so I can't install it.

Comment: If the databinding issue only exits after releasing on TestFlight, consider it's a potential issue, you can report on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues